# How does this "higher-order functions" thing works in Javascript

Tags: javascript, higher-order-functions, confirmation

From the book *Eloquent Javascript* by Marijn Haverbeke, there is [this example](http://eloquentjavascript.net/05_higher_order.html#h_xxCc98lOBK) while introducing the concept of higher-order functions:

```
function greaterThan(n) {
  return function(m) { return m > n; };
}
var greaterThan10 = greaterThan(10);
console.log(greaterThan10(11));
// → true
```

I'm not quite sure how this works...  probably answering my own question, but this is how I see it:

- First, `greaterThan(n)` is called in this line, assigning its value to the `greaterThan10` variable:

  ```
  var greaterThan10 = greaterThan(10);
  ```
- This makes the function stored as `greaterThan10` looks like:

  ```
  function greaterThan(10) {
    return function(m) { return m > 10; };
  }
  ```
- Then, when you call `greaterThan10(11)` you are calling the function above, which translates to:

  ```
  function greaterThan(10) {
    return function(11) { return 11 > 10; };
  }
  ```

  Hence returning `True` as the result as `11 > 10` is true indeed.

Could someone confirm whether I'm correct or not?  Also, if someone can provide further details and comments on how this higher-order functions work in JavaScript, that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Yes... here `n` is becoming a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) variable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're correct, from a level of understanding, but it's evaluated slightly differently.

```
var greaterThan10 = greaterThan(10);
```

This line doesn't make the function stored as `greaterThan10`  "look like" anything - it creates a new function, passing in the variable `n` to it, so that `greaterThan10` becomes a function that looks like

```
var greaterThan10 = function(m) { return m > 10; };
```

When you call it, you are calling this function directly, not going through the original function at all anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I also got confused while reading the example but later on reached the conclusion as below:

In chapter 3: functions, it has been explained how to declare a function using the arrow notation (`=>`). The arrow notation comes after the list of parameters, and if there is only one parameter then the parentheses can be ommitted around the parameter list. So, `m` is a parameter and not a function name.

So, after the first call to `greaterThan(10)`, `greaterThan10` essentially becomes

```
var greaterThan10 = function (m) { return m > 10; }
```

After the second call, `greaterThan10(11)`, it becomes

```
function (11) { return 11 > 10; }
```

11 > 10, which returns true.