# Calling a function by variable

Tags: javascript

I recently started to learn javascript by myself and I am reading a book called "Eloquent JavaScript". The following code is a sample script in the book which confused me:

```
function greaterThan(n) {
   return function(m) { return m > n; };
}
var greaterThan10 = greaterThan(10); 
console.log(greaterThan10(11));
```

Can someone please explain the logic of the last two lines? Does the `greaterThan10` contain a truth value or it is a function?

Comment: `greaterThan10` is a function.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does this "higher-order functions" thing works in Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31176240/how-does-this-higher-order-functions-thing-works-in-javascript). You could’ve just Googled “greaterThan Eloquent JavaScript”.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can look a little confusing at first, but just keep in mind that **functions are objects** in JavaScript.

`greaterThan(n)` is **a function that returns an anonymous function** with the definition:

```
function(m) { return m > n; }
```

Therefore, when we call `greaterThan(10)` we expect it to return an object that is in fact a function:

```
function(m) { return m > 10; }
```

Later on we just assign that object/function to a variable, and call it like we would call any function.

In short, just imagine that we had:

```
var greaterThan10 = function(m) { return m > 10; };
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! It makes sense now:D

Answer (score 1):

You define `greaterThan10` on the second to last line:

```
var greaterThan10 = greaterThan(10);
```

Whatever the `greaterThan` function returns in this case is what `greaterThan10` will evaluate to.

On line 2 we see that `greaterThan` will return the following function expression:

```
function(m) { return m > n; }
```

After replacing the variable `n` with the value you passed we get this:

```
function(m) { return m > 10; }
```